# SwiftMQ null pointer exception

Tags: java

I'm getting this null pointer exception when connecting using the 7.5.0 client to a 9.7.3 router running java8.  We are testing upgrading to Universal Router v12, but we're not quite ready.  Any suggestions?

```
Got Exception:
    ThreadGroup: mgmt
    ActiveTask : PipelineQueue, dispatchToken=sys$mgmt.dispatchqueue
Stack Trace: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.swiftmq.impl.mgmt.standard.v750.DispatcherImpl.doExpire(Unknown Source)
        at com.swiftmq.impl.mgmt.standard.DispatchQueue.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.swiftmq.impl.mgmt.standard.DispatchQueue.visit(Unknown Source)
        at com.swiftmq.impl.mgmt.standard.po.CheckExpire.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.swiftmq.tools.pipeline.PipelineQueue.process(Unknown Source)
        at com.swiftmq.tools.queue.SingleProcessorQueue.dequeue(Unknown Source)
        at com.swiftmq.tools.pipeline.PipelineQueue$QueueProcessor.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.swiftmq.impl.threadpool.standard.PoolThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please, provide more context

Comment: No idea. How could anybody without knowing your code? Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. You can avoid it in older releases by adding this attribute to the Management Swiftlet:

```
admintool-connect-logging-enabled="false"
```

Upgrading to 12.x is a good idea (fixed there).

If you want to get an answer on SwiftMQ related questions, please add tag `swiftmq` to your question, otherwise we won't get notified.

Comment: Thanks. FYI - the swiftmq tag doesn’t exist according to stackoverflow and my “rating” isn’t high enough to create new tags.